# C# - Adding views programmatically of unknown size

Tags: uiview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to add some views programmatically and from what I understand, you need to declare the size of view.

For example:

```
UITableView table = new UITableView(new CGRect(50, 0, 200, 100));
this.View.AddSubview(table);
```

But what if you don't know the size? What if this is dependent on dynamic data? Will the container simply expand as necessary?

I am trying to build a shopping cart interface. There are 3 main sections:

1. a TableView which contains the headers for the shopping basket (e.g. "Product Name", "Qty", etc).
2. A dynamic size Table which its size is dependent on the number of products contained in it.
3. Some checkout buttons underneath the cart.

Here is a really rough sample of what I'd like to see. The section in white is the dynamic area which will grow depending on how many items there are.

[image]

Currently what I'm doing is setting up one UITableView for the headings:

```
tableForHeaders = new UITableView(new CGRect(0, 0, screenWidth, 50));
tableForHeaders.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
tableForHeaders.Source = new UIShoppingCartHeaderTable.TableSource(headerRow);
this.View.AddSubview(tableForHeaders);
```

Then I have created another table for the line items (I won't bore you with my implementation of TableSource):

```
tableForRows = new UITableView(new CGRect(0, 50, screenWidth, this.View.Frame.GetMaxY()));
tableForRows.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
this.View.AddSubview(tableForRows);
```

And finally, I'm then trying to add the buttons in:

```
btnCheckout = new UIButton(new CGRect(0, 50 + tableForRows.ContentSize.Height, screenWidth, 50))
{
    BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red
};
btnCheckout.SetTitle("Checkout", UIControlState.Normal);
btnCheckout.SetTitleColor(UIColor.White, UIControlState.Normal);

btnContinue = new UIButton(new CGRect(0, 100 + tableForRows.ContentSize.Height, screenWidth, 50))
{
    BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red
};
btnContinue.SetTitle("Continue", UIControlState.Normal);
btnContinue.SetTitleColor(UIColor.White, UIControlState.Normal);

this.View.AddSubview(btnCheckout);
this.View.AddSubview(btnContinue);
```

I set the height of tableForRows to be GetMaxY() - as I thought this might be the best way to leave it as big as possible. I'm then trying to set the height of the buttons to be ContentSize.Height. Again, I'm sure I've done this wrong, just not sure how to logically do this.

Answer (score 0):

if you want full size view in your app then its like this

```
#define SCREEN_WIDTH  [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width
#define SCREEN_HT     [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height

tableViewForActivities=[[UITableView alloc]init];
tableViewForActivities.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HT);

suppose width=50 hight =50
```

if you want view in centre then by giving width it will adjust automatically within any iOS device

```
view=  [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((SCREEN_WIDTH-width)/2, 0,  width, width)];
```

Thank you

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't clarify that I was dealing with C#. I've also amended my OP so that you can get a better understanding of what I'm trying to achieve. I do not necessary want to make it full size either... I just want it to consume as much space as it needs. I'd then like my next view to be directly under it.

Answer (score 0):

you can just put this for

```
view2 =  [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((SCREEN_WIDTH-width)/2, CGRectGetMaxY(view.frame),  width, width)];
```

i think this will help you

Comment: Are you able to provide the C# version for this? CGRectGetMaxY doesn't appear to exist.

Comment: no sir i only know Objective c code as you tagged with Ios Tag

Comment: Xamarin iOS is .NET programming. With your suggestion, can you clarify what this should do? Does this make the container scalable as needed?

Comment: Sure, if you could clarify what it does?

Comment: it gives maximum value of y - coordinate . but use in ios sir

Comment: suppose width=50 hight =50
productView=  [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((SCREEN_WIDTH-width)/2, 0,  width, width)];

 qtyView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((SCREEN_WIDTH-width)/2, CGRectGetMaxY(productView.frame),  width, width)];

Comment: Getting the maximum value is not what i want to do. I want it to only use as much space as necessary. This could be 50 this could be 500. I then want some other views to display directly under the dynamicly sized one.

Comment: i can tell only in objective c, sorry sir

Comment: Understood, and that's fine. But what you've suggested still doesn't make sense for objective C.